# Remove spacing between table rows

Tags: html, css, html-email

I've looked through many of the similarly titled questions regarding this issue, and tried many of the accepted answers but am still getting the unwanted row spaces. Like many of the questions, I'm making an email template so I have to use nested tables to get not only the structure I want, but for it to render properly in email.

The solutions I've tried that have not worked:

1. cellspacing = 0
2. cellpading = 0
3. border-collapse: collapse
4. border-spacing: 0
5. margin: 0 0 0 0
6. style="display: block" for my image

None of these seem to even make a difference, I can't get rid of the row spaces. This happens in Chrome/IE/Firefox.

[image]

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <title>
          Title
        </title>
        <style type="text/css">
        a:hover { text-decoration: none !important; }
        .header h1 {color: #055d90; font: normal 25px Georgia, Times, serif; margin: 0; font-weight: bold; padding: 0 0 0px 0; line-height: 39px; margin-top: 0;}
        .header p {color: #cf373e; font: normal 17px Georgia, Times, serif; margin: 0; padding: 0; line-height: 12px; font-style: italic;}
        .custinfo h1 {color: #FFFFFF; font: normal 25px Tahoma, Times, serif; background-color: #FF8000; padding: 10px 0 10px 0;}
        .custinfo h2 {color: #FFFFFF; font: normal 15px Tahoma, Times, serif; background-color: #707070; padding: 0 0 0 0;}
        .table {border-collapse: collapse;}
        .table td {margin: 0; padding: 0; display:block;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body style="margin: 0; padding: 0;">
        <table align="left" width="100%" class="table">
            <tr>
            <!--header-->
                <table class="table"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; margin-top: 0;">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <img src="images/logo.gif" style="display: block; border: 0" alt="" width="200" height="100">
                        </td>                       
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top" align="middle" class="header" width="100%">
                            <h1>Order</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr class="custinfo">
                        <td width="50%">
                            <h1>[DISTRIBUTOR NAME]</h1>                         
                        </td> 
                        <td align="middle">
                            <h1>[ORDER DATE]</h1>
                        </td>
                    </tr>                   
                </table>
                <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;">
                    <tr class="custinfo">
                        <td>
                            <h2>PO# [PO NUMBER]</h2>                                    
                        </td> 
                        <td >
                            <h2>Customer [COMPANY NAME]</h2>
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <h2>Total Order [TOTAL ORDER]</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="custinfo" style="margin:0">
                        <td>
                            <h2>PO# [PO NUMBER]</h2>                                    
                        </td> 
                        <td>
                            <h2>Customer [COMPANY NAME]</h2>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <h2>Total Order [TOTAL ORDER]</h2>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: adding padding:0 help? From the css you provided, i did not see an explicit padding initialization. Probaby the p[adding is what adding the space

Comment: I just realized what it was. When I created the additional css styles for custinfo headers, I didn't add the margin: 0 part

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should prevent `h1`, `h2` elements from margin collapsing.

```
h1, h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```css
a:hover {
  text-decoration: none !important;
}
.header h1 {
  color: #055d90;
  font: normal 25px Georgia, Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0 0 0px 0;
  line-height: 39px;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.header p {
  color: #cf373e;
  font: normal 17px Georgia, Times, serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.custinfo h1 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: normal 25px Tahoma, Times, serif;
  background-color: #FF8000;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
}
.custinfo h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: normal 15px Tahoma, Times, serif;
  background-color: #707070;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
.table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
.table td {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
}
h1,
h2 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<table align="left" width="100%" class="table">
  <tr>
    <!--header-->
    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0; margin-top: 0;">
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">
          <img src="images/logo.gif" style="display: block; border: 0" alt="" width="200" height="100">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" align="middle" class="header" width="100%">
          <h1>Order</h1>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;">
      <tr class="custinfo">
        <td width="50%">
          <h1>[DISTRIBUTOR NAME]</h1> 
        </td>
        <td align="middle">
          <h1>[ORDER DATE]</h1>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;">
      <tr class="custinfo">
        <td>
          <h2>PO# [PO NUMBER]</h2> 
        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>Customer [COMPANY NAME]</h2>

        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>Total Order [TOTAL ORDER]</h2>

        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="custinfo" style="margin:0">
        <td>
          <h2>PO# [PO NUMBER]</h2> 
        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>Customer [COMPANY NAME]</h2>

        </td>
        <td>
          <h2>Total Order [TOTAL ORDER]</h2>

        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Reference: [Margin collapsing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing)

Comment: Yea this was it, in my custinfo h1 and h2 attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Add margin: 0 to your h2. If you not define margin 0 the margin comes default with user agent stylesheets.

JSFiddle Link

```
https://jsfiddle.net/aLast0qs/
```

Css code

```
.custinfo h2 {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font: normal 15px Tahoma, Times, serif;
  background-color: #707070;
  padding: 0 0 0 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```